# Como puedo solucionar el siguiente error al importar keras?

Tags: python, redes, dataset, keras, redes-neuronales

-Estoy realizando una red neuronal, pero me genera el siguiente error al importar keras

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'transpose_shape' from 'keras.utils.generic_utils' (C:\Users\any-0\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este tipo de errores suele darse porque tienes versiones de `Tensorflow` y `Keras` incompatibles. `Keras` suele usar `Tensorflow` como backend por lo que si tienes versiones incompatibles, te encontrarás este tipo de errores.

Lo optimo es que si estás ejecutando un proyecto, tengas el archivo `requirements.txt` en el que se encuentren las versiones de las librerías con las que se creo el proyecto, así no hay incompatibilidades.

Si no tienes algo así, te recomiendo que desinstales las versiones que tienes y pruebes versiones, o **trates de adaptar el código**. Una de las versiones con menos fallos, es alguna que ya tenga un tiempo y que haya recibido muchos parches, por ejemplo:

- Python 3.7
- keras 2.3
- Tensorflow 2.1